# How to cast a 2 Dimentionnal array to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I want to make an `ObservableCollection` with **2D array**

How can I achieve that ?

I already test : `myarrat.Cast<int<[,]>>()`

```
ObservableCollection<int[,]> TheObservableCollection = 
  new ObservableCollection<int[,]>(my2DArray);
```

Comment: What is `my2DArray`? What is the error you get?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] showing us how you are populating the 2D array.

Comment: Doesn't casting to an ObservableCollection potentially break the purpose of an ObservableCollection? The whole point of an ObservableCollection is that it can fire events when you add or remove elements on it.  I assume you're trying to cast an array directly to an ObservableCollection so that you can then assign the cast value to a member ObservableCollection variable.  What is the expected application behavior when you do that?  Typically when working with collections like this, you want to add/remove elements or call AddRange or the similar removal if they implement it.

Comment: Well, ObservableCollection constructor allow only List<T> or IEnumerable<T>. But Multi dimentional array implement only IEnumerable. That's kind of un intuitive.

Comment: You could add an extention and make it an Ienumerable<T> with something like : `static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T[,] array)
{
 foreach (var item in array)
  yield return item;
}`. But you will end up with an ObservableCollection<int>.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is a `int[][] jaggedArray =
            {
                new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 },
                new int[] { 0, 2, 4, 6 },
                new int[] { 11, 22 }
            };

            var foo = new ObservableCollection<int[]>(jaggedArray);`